# The error entitled " miktex-makemf did not succeed." problem

Tags: errors, miktex

I got this error. Could anybody explain it please?

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C

:\Users\Hi\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Hi\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Process exited with error(s)

While installing it just remains here:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a small compilable document reproducing the error?

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you want?

Comment: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
destination with the same identifier (name{page.0}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.136 \maketitle [0]
Overfull \hbox (123.62721pt too wide) detected
Ignoring empty anchor
Ignoring empty anchor
I

Comment: As we do not have a crystal ball, we need a small complete code that displays the same error messages, to test it and try to find a solution.

Comment: I cannot send the code since it is a paper and I do not know which part has the problem

Comment: Actually it was working recently but I update and it does not work now

Comment: Which font do you use?

Comment: \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}

Comment: It worked before!!

Comment: If MiKTeX tries to use makepk, it means it doesn't find the type 1 (vector)  fonts. Try opening the `Tasks` menu in MiKTeX console and click on `Refresh font map files` to refresh the type 1 fonts database.

Comment: I did that. Now I got another error calc.sty is not found. require package

Comment: The required  `tools` package has changed name, and is now `latex-tools`. Check whether it is installed, and install it if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you bernard. How can I do that? Actually, even now it gives an error File `elsarticle.cls' not found. \usepackage. I do not know what happened suddenly!!

Comment: Is elsarticle installed? To install a package, run MiKTeX Package manager, right click  on the package you want to install, and click on ‘Install’ in the pop-up menu that appears, that's all.

Comment: Look. Everything was worked until today that I want to run the template for an elsevier journal! After that everything is shut down!!

Comment: code="35", url="https://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma"

Comment: It gives this error while installing!!

Comment: I have no idea a priori, but elsarticle is not installed by default. Just in case  something happened when you updated, you can try runnin g`Refresh filenames database` from the `Tasks`menu in MiKTeX console.

Comment: Bernard look when I want to install what happened it just awaits here Is this common? how long  does it take?

Comment: At most a couple of minutes, if you chose a not too far repository and you have a correct connection.

Comment: SSL connect error :(